# Want to execute a script to reduce my repetitive commands whenever I open a server.how to write a simple script for it?

Tags: shell

Below commands have to be in script so that I can reduce repetitive steps whenever I enter into a server.

```
cd /opt/app/*
ls -ltr
```

script file to run like path.sh

Answer (score 0):

When you make a script like this, and call it by `path.sh` (executable script in your PATH, did you add `$HOME/bin` to the PATH?), it will be executed in a subshell.
When you make changes in the environment of your shell (working directory with `cd ...` or changing shell variables), these get lost after completion of the script.
You can `source path.sh` for making the changes last, but you need to remember this every time.
An alternative is using an alias, but you should consider a function.
Put something like this function in your `.profile` or `.bash_rc`:

```
showapp() {
   cd /opt/app
   ls -lrt
}
```

I removed the wildcard in your `cd` command, the `cd` can only jump to one location.
After calling this function you will be in /opt/app. If you don't need this, you might want `ls -rtl /opt/app`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I'm new for scripting I just want to know to whether it is possible to directly get into those path instead having repetition each time.

Comment: Yes, with a function or alias or command in your login code as explained above.